# PHP curl post not received by ruby server

Tags: php, ruby, post, httprequest, tcpserver

I have a simple ruby server implemented with TCPServer and I need to call it via a POST request from a different server running PHP. The ruby server replies when I do a cURL in the terminal or access it in a browser, but not when called via cURL from the PHP server. I also tried calling fopen / stream_get_contents and that also didn't work. Also, cURL works fine on the PHP server with other apps...

Here's my PHP function:

```
<?php
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'RUBY_SERVER_IP:RUBY_SERVER_PORT');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'test=test');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$updates = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$output = curl_getinfo($curl_handle);
print_r($output);

curl_close($curl_handle);
?>
```

And here's the Ruby server:

```
require "socket"

server = TCPServer.new(80)

loop {
    client = server.accept
    response = "<html>Got it</html>"
    headers = ["HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
             "Server: Ruby",
             "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1",
             "Content-Length: #{response.length}\r\n\r\n"].join("\r\n")
    client.puts headers
    client.puts response
    client.close
}
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not take advantage of something like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), which makes it trivial to create HTTP services?

Comment: I was thinking about that too @theTinMan, but I wanted to keep it simple since I'm running the Ruby server on a Raspberry Pi. I'll give Sinatra a try and come back with updates.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work